# Center align LI when there is Float left

Tags: html, css

Folllowing is my jsfiddle in which I am trying to center align the list items `<li>` into `<ul>` .  **Only problem is lis are set to float left and I can not remove this condition**. Kindly let me know is there a way to tackle float left and make lis center aligned generically (in responsive manner)?

http://jsfiddle.net/AqRJA/2/

```
#nav{
    text-align: center;
    line-height:30px;
}

#nav li {
    float: left;
}

#nav li {
    list-style:none;
    margin: 0 5px;
    display:inline;
    border:gray solid 1px;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### [Demo Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/AqRJA/12/)

Why not simply add:

```
#nav ul{
    display:inline-block;
}
```

Comment: Thanks but its actually happening cause of the div, Kindly let me know how to make this fiddle center aligned: http://jsfiddle.net/AqRJA/22/

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/swfour/AqRJA/24/ - if you cant change your HTML to wrap within another element, or remove the float, you cannot otherwise accomplish what you want. It would be effectively like trying to paint your house blue using red paint :(

Comment: Thanks for all your help, damn there is a need of `float: center` I really wonder some time why there is no center when there is left and right

Comment: @user3027531 sorry there isnt the solution you're after, appreciate it isnt ideal

Answer (score 0):

Try like this: **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/AqRJA/10/)**

CSS:

```
#nav ul {
    margin:0 auto;
}
#nav li {
    list-style:none;
    margin: 0 5px;
    display:inline-block;
    border:gray solid 1px;
}
```